# is it possibe to drop the push notification in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a requierement like if local storage id and push payload id matches then only display the notification in notification bar or else drop the notification. In foreground i can drop using callback method `willPresentNotification` but am unable to find any solution when the app is in background or inactive. Please suggest me is it possible to drop notification?

Comment: May be just doesn't send notification on device with particular local storage id?

Comment: It is strange to push to all devices a notification meant only to one of them. Do it on the server side.

Comment: sometimes api call get failed while updating the id or some other reasons just want to put the condition from app side also.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy I mean while receiving the push in device just check the condition and display or hide the push.